# output is null when passing String str=null

Tags: java

```
public class StringTest
{
    public static void main(String... args)
    {
        String str=null;
        System.out.println(str);
    }
}
```

why this code display null? when we pass reference variable into `println()` method it will call `toString()` method. For String class, `toString()` method will be call that returns current object. `String str=null` means no object is existing.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#println%28java.lang.String%29) reports `System.out.println(String)`:

> Prints a String and then terminate the line. This method behaves as though it invokes `print(String)` and then `println()`.

and the [documentation](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29) for `print(String)` reports:

> Prints a string. **If the argument is `null` then the string "null" is printed**. Otherwise, the string's characters are converted into bytes according to the platform's default character encoding, and these bytes are written in exactly the manner of the `write(int)` method.

Answer (score 1):

Your answer is [here](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/io/PrintStream.html#print%28java.lang.String%29):

> Print a string. **If the argument is null then the string "null" is
>   printed**.

Note that "*This method behaves as though it invokes print(String) and then println()*"

Answer (score 0):

Try 
String str="";

null means theres nothing in that memory space... if you use "" that blank space inside will count, will make a space memory for that variable at same time will show nothing ( i think thats it)